Finding if roots of a polynomial function are shifted when adding another polynomial function?
Not sure if this question has an easy answer but I was wondering if there is a heuristic or some theorem that helps proving which way the roots are being shifted for an equation $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$.
For a specific example, $g(x)$ is a polynomial of order$\geq 1$ with only 1 real root in the vicinity $0<x<1$, and $h(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n} (x-k), n \in \mathbb{N}$ which has roots $x=0,1,...,n$ all on the right hand side except for $0$. Is there a way to know if the roots will stay on the right hand side or not for $f(x)$? Or is there a theorem which would help with finding if the roots shift a certain direction?

How would you define the shift?

We are told nothing at all about g(x) for x>1 or for x<0. It could be very large or very small or bounce around a lot. So it seems unlikely that you can say very much about the roots of f(x).
Or perhaps you mean that g(x) only has 1 real root in total - and that is between 0 and 1. That would help a bit.

Yes only one real root
